# How to Implement 'Show Touches' programmatically?

Tags: android, android-source

Android has a feature named 'Show Touches' in 'Settings->Developer Options',  which enable showing a visual feedback for touch interactions. And I want to know how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can learn from `PointerLocationView.java` and `PhoneWindowManager.java` in AOSP which can implement the similar function.

Comment: this isn't very explanatory, how exactly can you do it?

Answer (score 4):

you can Enable and disable by using following code

Add permission in manifest first

```
 android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
```

Note: If the app targets API level 23 or higher, the app user must explicitly grant this permission to the app through a permission management screen. The app requests the user's approval by sending an intent with action ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS. The app can check whether it has this authorization by calling Settings.System.canWrite().

Read [Manifest.permission](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html)

**Enable**

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),"show_touches", 1);
```

**Disable**

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), "show_touches", 0);
```

Comment: thanks，And  I want to know how it implements,I mean I want to implement this function myself.Do you know how it implements？

Comment: if you want to create similar feature in whole system - it's not possible due to proper system-low-level permissions acquired ("Settings" app is part of system). you may only create smth similar inside your app (look for dispatching touch events) or maybe try with root and/or custom room

Comment: I am customising my own android system,and I will compile it in AOSP in the end.But I don`t know how to implement the function.Do you know how to implemet it or how AOSP implements it(location of source code in AOSP)?